# Org-mode function to duplicate current header and change ID

Tags: org-mode

I noticed I copy-paste entire headers (with content) quite often. The problem I also notice is that this creates a lot of headers with duplicate IDs. I wonder if anyone has a function he would like to share or can help me create a function that will

1. copy current header and contents (`org-copy-subtree`) at point
2. paste it below current header
3. change ID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I often need to copy/paste a large tree and had the same problem with duplicate ids.  Now, after pasting the tree, I **narrow to the tree** and run the following function.  This will visit every heading at any level in the tree and either change its id or, for newly-created headings, give it an id.

```
(defun bw/org-add-update-ids-to-headlines-in-file ()
  "Add ID properties to all visible headlines in the current file which
do not already have one.  Change the IDs of those that already have them."
  (interactive)
  (org-map-entries '(lambda () (org-id-get-create t))))

(spacemacs/set-leader-keys "oa" 'bw/org-add-update-ids-to-headlines-in-file)
```

Maybe I should also look into adding an id automatically every time I create a new heading...